# How can I converse with people on Facebook using an email client and no browser?

Tags: email, browser, automation, email-client, facebook

I don't like Facebook for a host of reasons, and have avoided setting up an account. However, I'm under pressure to do so because of group communications which are taking place on Facebook solely, in a certain Facebook group, leaving me "out of the loop".

I was thinking that perhaps I could utilize Facebook's auto-generated email addresses, and their email notification mechanism, to arrange it so that I only use an email client to conduct Facebook business:

- Be sent a copy of new posts/notes/comments/whatever (i.e. the contents, not just the notice of its existence)
- Be sent a copy, or a direct link, to files that are posted
- Be able to post replies/notes/comments/whatever in continuation of discussions - by sending email
- Avoid being sent other things I'm not interested in, like requests to 'friend' me etc.
- Be notified whenever a relevant discussion/thread/exchange-of-comments/wall-notes/whatever is started

I also thought maybe there's some less-direct way to achieve this, e.g. a mail client plugin, a server constituting some Facebook-to-email bridge, etc.

**Notes:**

- I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird as a mail client.
- I would rather avoid solutions based on proprietary software and/or Facebook's commercial collaborations.

Answer (score 0):

In **Facebook | Notification | e-mail** you can customize receiving email notifications of events that you would already be notified of on Facebook, (so this essentially auto-forwards notifications from Facebook to your specified email) - although I don't believe that would work for conversing with others very well.

Other alternatives to not using the Facebook site would be linking your Facebook account with other applications like [Skype](http://www.skype.com/en/) or using some sort of social media management like [hootsuite](https://hootsuite.com/).

Comment: See my updated notes in the question. I will check out hootsuite though.